# Why "svn log -g" for including merged revisions in log output takes forever?

Tags: svn, history, merge, version-control

For viewing all commits in `svn log` including those commits which are part of the merged branches `-g` option must be used. But executing `svn log -g` on the SVN repository which I'm working with seems to take forever to complete. This started to happen when some amount of commits and merges was accumulated in the repository which is currently at revision 4913.

What can be the reason for such a behavior and does it exist some way to overcome it?